# Strange error trying to manipulate local variable with write_volatile

Tags: rust

I was trying to modify values using `read_volatile` and `write_volatile` functions in rust, but I got a strange error.

I tried to count from 0 to 1 billion.

this is the code

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = 0u32;
    let t = (&x as *const u32) as *mut u32;
    for _ in 0..1000000000 {
        unsafe {
            core::ptr::write_volatile(t, core::ptr::read_volatile(t) + 1);
        }
    }
    println!("{:?}", x)
}
```

I got an error stating:

```
error: assigning to `&T` is undefined behavior, consider using an `UnsafeCell`
  --> src/main.rs:30:13
   |
27 |     let t = (&x as *const u32) as *mut u32;
   |           ------------------------------ casting happend here
...
30 |             core::ptr::write_volatile(t, core::ptr::read_volatile(t) + 1);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: for more information, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html>
   = note: `#[deny(invalid_reference_casting)]` on by default
```

Comment: The compiler tells you what the problem is.

Comment: why  cont i do it with above method?

Comment: Do I need to quote what the compile says?  `assigning to \`&T\` is undefined behavior, consider using an \`UnsafeCell\``.

Comment: can any one explain why this error occur or what's happening  when i try to use read_volatile method???

Comment: Do you know what "undefined behaviour" means? It's jargon, and if you don't know the exact meaning, go look it up. And if you still have questions, you can ask about it here.

Comment: The compiler is preventing you from writing code that causes undefined behavior. The built-in compiler lint is stopping your code from compiling: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/lints/listing/deny-by-default.html#invalid-reference-casting

Comment: Because you assign to `&T`, i.e. a shared reference. I think the compiler is as clear as you can get. Please take time to look at the code and the error and correlate them.

Comment: If you declare `x` as mutable, then initialise `t` with `&mut x as *mut u32`, the compiler will stop complaining because the operation mutates something that is actually mutable. You cannot pretend `x` is not mutable and mutate it anyway. This is where `UnsafeCell` can help, as suggested by the compiler.

Comment: You guys are rough with the OP. Rust is not generally an easy language to understand nor is what the compiler saying obvious to anyone unfamiliar with it. If he would have understood what the compiler said, he wouldn't have asked a question.

Comment: In this case I have to side with OP — the compiler didn't say the more obvious fix, “make `x` mutable if you want to mutate it”.

Comment: When you start casting references to raw pointers I don't think you can expect compiler to give you more "helpful" hints.

Answer (score 2):

Since my comment seemed to be appreciated, here is a developed version as an answer, in case it could be found useful.

Declaring `x` as not mutable lets the compiler suppose that no circumstances could make the value of this variable change.
Then, the compiler is free to reuse its initial value everywhere `x` is mentioned in the subsequent source code.
This does not mean that it actually does that, but it could decide to behave like this, now or in a future version.
In this sense, using an ugly hack to take the address of this variable and mutate it anyway (after some type coercions) is an undefined behaviour : the compiler could either decide to consider that this mutation actually happens on the *pretended* immutable `x`, and then consider its modified value in the subsequent code, or simply decide this value is immutable and ignore the tricky mutations.

If you declare `x` as mutable and initialise `t` with `&mut x as *mut u32`, then the compiler will stop complaining because the operation mutates something that is actually mutable.
And even with `cargo +nightly miri run`, no error is reported.

In its diagnostic, the compiler suggests using `UnsafeCell` because this type exists exactly for this purpose: tell the compiler that an apparently immutable data could however be mutated in certain circumstances (the usage of its `.get()` method).
In this situation, the compiler is conservative and will generate memory accesses in order to actually read the value of this data although this `UnsafeCell` is not declared as mutable.

As mentioned in a comment, in your situation the compiler could have simply suggested to make `x` mutable.